# collision detection - ray casting too many objects?

Tags: three.js, raycasting, jsperf

I have made a dynamic maze out of voxels, it looke like this:[Map logged to console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjDms.png)

At that size its using about 780 voxels.

Im using a camera to fly around but I can walk through walls.

What is the best way to detect collisions?

If I loop through 700+ objects, each render loop to ray cast, I expect this to cause a huge bottle neck or is 700+ objects nothing to worry about?

Thanks.

Comment: check out raycasting using an octree at http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_octree_raycasting

Comment: Just to speak regarding gaitat's link. An often used technique for fast collision detection is to have two phases. You first have a broad phase algorithm, that is extremely fast (octree), that eliminates the majority of contenders and provides a small list to check thoroughly. You then run a narrow phase algorithm, which takes the smaller list from the previous algorithm and does a more rigorous test to determine the real collisions (ray casting).